# Discord.js getting guildmember from username

Tags: discord.js

I hope you can help I can't seem to find a solution for this speific use case.

When a user joins my server I want to show a welcome embed and update their nickname in the server.

I have the embed bit working fine but I cant seem to get the guildMember using the user supplied.

code: Discord.js v12.2

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member=> {
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'cloudservertesting');
if(!channel) return;

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#992D22')
    .setTitle('New Member')
    .setDescription(`**${member.user.username}** has joined Red Wine Gaming!, Welcome!`)
        .setThumbnail(`${member.user.displayAvatarURL()}`)
    .setTimestamp();
channel.send(embed);
//Change users Nickname Here
```

});

member.guild.members returns an object but it wont let me .filter

It would be ideal if I could get the guildmember from the mumer.user supplied on the user add so i can setNickname.

Answer (score 0):

The [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) instance you're looking for is your parameter `member`. Check the documentation on the [`Client#guildMemberAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd) event and you'll see the parameter is a GuildMember.

```js
member.setNickname('foo')
  .catch(console.error);
```

---

> member.guild.members returns an object but it wont let me .filter

That would be because as of v12, it's a Manager, so you would have to utilize the `cache` property to use `Collection#filter()`. See [GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) specifically.